Closed-form formula of elments' locations from the Lehmer code
Q: Given the Lehmer Code (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) of a permutation $\sigma$:
$$L(\sigma)=(L(\sigma)_1,\ldots,L(\sigma)_n)\quad\text{where}\quad L(\sigma)_i=\#\{ j>i : \sigma_j<\sigma_i \},$$
what is the closed-form formula for the location of each element $i$, i.e., $\sigma_i$?
I know we can use a decoding algorithm to recover the permutation, but it is unclear to me what can be a closed-form formula.

Not an answer to your question, but an inspiring paper here.
